# Can I change the font of all elements in my barchart with one property?

Tags: fonts, plotting

I have this BarChart:

[image]

created with this code:

```
sizes = {10718, 881, 395, 387, 375, 309, 297};
BarChart[sizes, ChartStyle -> 33, ImageSize -> 480, BarOrigin -> Left, ChartLabels -> 
  Placed[sizes, {{1, 0.25}, {0, 0}}, "  " <> ToString[#] <> " kB" &], 
ChartLegends -> {"DelphiXE3", "Delphi2010", "Delphi2005", "Delphi7", 
  "Delphi6", "Delphi5", "Delphi4"}]
```

Now I want all of the text: ChartLabels, ChartLegends and tick labels in Helvetica. Can I do this with a single property, or do I have to add the property for each of the three elements separately? And how do I either?

Comment: `BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]`. This probably should be merged with your previous question.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch - Thanks again. Not sure about merging; the data is the same, but here it's about the font globally, which wasn't in the other question.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch - This doesn't seem to change the font for the legends.

Comment: ok. see answer below

Answer (score 3):

On its own `LabelStyle` works for me so long as rules are given as a `List`, not a `Directive`.

Minimal example:

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3},
 ChartLegends -> {"one", "two", "three"}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> "Trajan Pro"}
]
```

[image]

Your full example chart:

```
sizes = {10718, 881, 395, 387, 375, 309, 297};

BarChart[sizes,
 ChartStyle -> 33,
 ImageSize -> 480,
 BarOrigin -> Left, 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[sizes, {{1, 0.25}, {0, 0}}, "  " <> ToString[#] <> " kB" &], 
 ChartLegends -> {"DelphiXE3", "Delphi2010", "Delphi2005", "Delphi7", "Delphi6", 
   "Delphi5", "Delphi4"},
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> "Trajan Pro"}
]
```

[image]

Trajan Pro is a distinctive small-caps font I happen to have installed.  Substitute Helvetica for deployment.

Comment: Trajan? You'll [annoy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t87QKdOJNv8) the internets... :)

Comment: @cormullion My only defense is that I was using it before it was overused (I think).  Here it merely serves as a distinctive font I have available.  I used Comic Sans for that purpose until I saw torches and pitchforks. :o)  Got another suggestion for a distinctive font selection, preferably freeware?

Comment: Just pick one from [here](http://www.dafont.com/themes.php) - lots to choose from... :)

Comment: Failure of `Directive` would be a bug

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I suppose so.  No upvote?  Isn't at least "This answer is useful?"

Comment: haven't upvoted because I didn't think the question was warranted in the first place--see my comment above. This is just a minor follow on from the previous question and therefore I showed how using the 3rd argument to `Placed` described in answer to that question, gives a result.

Answer (score 1):

```
sizes = {10718, 881, 395, 387, 375, 309, 297};
font = "Helvetica";
BarChart[sizes, BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> font],  
 ChartStyle -> 33, ImageSize -> 480, BarOrigin -> Left, 
 ChartLabels -> 
  Placed[sizes, {{1, 0.25}, {0, 0}}, "  " <> ToString[#] <> " kB" &], 
 ChartLegends -> 
  Placed[{"DelphiXE3", "Delphi2010", "Delphi2005", "Delphi7", 
    "Delphi6", "Delphi5", "Delphi4"}, Right, 
   Style[#, FontFamily -> font] &]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I presume the "14" is supposed to change the font size, but it doesn't do anything, not even when I add "FontSize->" in front of it. This did work for the BaseStyle solution you suggested in comment.

Comment: sorry `ChartBaseStyle` is redundant in this example.