# VectorPlot differences between v9 and v10

Tags: graphics

The following code displays differently with v9 & v10:

```
VectorPlot[{1, 2 x (1 - x)}, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, 
VectorScale -> {.03, Automatic, None}, 
VectorStyle -> {Red, "Segment"}]
```

In v9 the arrowheads are not present. This is the image I want. [image: No arrowheads here]

In v10, arrowheads are present and I do not want them. [image: with arrowheads]

I have tried using VectorStyle->{Red,Arrowheads[0]} in v10 but to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion `VectorStyle -> {Red, "Segment"}` should *not* work in the way you illustrate as it should be interpreted as styling for two different vector fields and in version 10 it is.  [`Directive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Directive.html) should work but apparently it does not.

What *does* work in version 10 is a `List` of directives one level down, e.g.:

```
VectorStyle -> {{dir1, dir2, ...}, ...}
```

For your example:

```
VectorPlot[{1, 2 x (1 - x)}, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1},
 VectorScale -> {.03, Automatic, None}, 
 VectorStyle -> {{Red, "Segment"}}]
```

[image]

---

Related: [Can I change the font of all elements in my barchart with one property?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54794/121)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a workaround:

```
VectorPlot[{1, 2 x (1 - x)}, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1},
 VectorScale -> {.03, Automatic, None},
 VectorStyle -> Arrowheads[0],
 VectorColorFunction -> {Hue[#*0] &}]
```

[image]

The whole thing seems to be buggy in **V10**

Comment: This works alright. (Note that your parens in the last line need to be curly braces.) "Segment" also works in place of Arrowheads[0].